# TinyMCE - Removing content

Tags: tinymce

I'm using TinMCE to edit site content and need to add a custom piece of HTML via a button using TinyMCE plugin so when i click the button the following content gets added:

```
<div class="custom">
    <a class="header">title</a>
    <a class="delete">delete</a>
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

This is all working however I want to add a link so when I click delete the div gets removed from the TinyMCE content.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: so you want to click inside the editor html button ('delete') and perform an action?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tinyMCE 4.X, it can be done using the <> source code editor option under tools. when you open it, you will see the html source code for what you have entered in the tinyMC editor.

```
<div class="custom">
    <a class="header">title</a>
    <a class="delete" onclick="this.parentNode.remove();">delete</a>
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

just make sure you have added anchor's onclick as extended_valid_elements
e.g.

```
tinymce.init({
...
extended_valid_elements : "a[onclick]"
... });
```

for more.... check this out : 
[http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:extended_valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aextended_valid_elements)